# Como uma closure funciona internamente?

Tags: c#, .net, função-anônima, closures, clr

Como a variável é capturada em uma *closure*? É de forma igual para tipo por valor ou por referência? Há *boxing* no caso de ser por valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável é capturada com a ajuda de uma classe auxiliar criada pelo compilador.

Em essência não há diferença para o tipo do objeto. Lembre-se que a captura é feita pela variável, não necessariamente o objeto.

Estritamente falando não há *boxing*. Mas como a variável por valor que poderia ser usada na pilha, passa para uma classe que vai para o *heap*, então o efeito é quase o mesmo, mas o mecanismo de *boxing* não acontece.

Para entender melhor vamos a um código que mostra o que o compilador faz:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Action closure = Test();
        closure();
        closure();
    }
    static Action Test() {
        int counter = 0;
        return () => Console.WriteLine(counter++);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/scWLKQ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OkFqxE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Closure.cs).

O compilador faz algo parecido com isto (de forma bem simplificada só para entender):

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Action closure = Test();
        closure();
        closure();
    }
    static Action Test() {
        Closure local = new Closure();
        local.counter = 0;
        return local.Function;
    }
}
//gerado pelo compilador
class Closure {
    public int counter;
    public void Function() => Console.WriteLine(counter++);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tk5mkz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FhLps). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/ClosuereInternal.cs).

Se quiser pode ver o [código real que ele gera](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDNgAinA7Gg3stQjOANgwBY0BZAQwEsA7ACgEo8CjPMY0BjAGwD2AZwCuAJwCmaALxoAKpOEAXVgG4OnQgJETJ6zVp1ipBpJwC+hzGW4KlqtvnNbCjZX0GiGyyeNloAAwaLq5QOKyyAHzEAJxMvF4+fmBgLCGWyBZAA=).

Eu gostaria que existisse um mecanismo alternativo mais eficiente para casos que dá para garantir que não escape longe, o que não é fácil de fazer no compilador, teria que ter ajuda do programador. Em alguns casos retornar o valor (mesmo que seja um ponteiro) junto com a referência para o tipo a ser usado deveria ser suficiente, assim não precisaria alocar memória para a classe.