# O que são ValueTasks?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Estava implementando o método assíncrono `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()` na minha classe para oferecer um desconstrutor aguardável, e me deparei que o retorno desse método deve ser um `ValueTask`.

Fiquei em dúvida sobre o que é, para que serve, quando e como devo usar `ValueTask`?

Answer (score 0):

Sabe o que é uma [`Task`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101)? É essencialmente a mesma coisa, mas em vez de ser uma classe é uma estrutura, ou seja, é por valor, dando mais eficiência no uso em casos que a tarefa não escapa longe e vai usar só para comunicar entre os métodos diretamente ligados na transição de tarefas. A função não muda, é só a forma de carregar estado da tarefa até a conclusão total dela. ([ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321190/101)).

Quase sempre ela é preferível do que a `Task` porque não tem alocação no *heap*. Quando não tem controle para onde a tarefa vai, se ela vai navegar por vários métodos e não sabe o que pode acontecer, se vai para dentro de um objeto, o tempo de vida é indeterminado, aí fica complicado.

Com ela é que poderá pegar um possível valor que a tarefa gera de forma assíncrona, como faz com a `Task`.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Curiosamente hoje falei da [necessidade de uma `ValueClosure`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/580367/101).